# Does an expression allocate memory?

Tags: performance, compilation, coding-style, variable-assignment

Consider two code snippets:

```
if (1 + 2 == 3) {
}
```

and

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int result = 3;
int addition_result = a + b;
bool comparison = addition_result == result;

if (comparison) {
}
```

Are these snippets essentially the same? In the first case, does the compiler allocate memory at execution time for all operands:

- `1`
- `2`
- `3`
- `1 + 2`
- `1 + 2 == 3` (to compare it to `true`)

or is the first snippet more efficient because the compiler does not have to allocate any memory for that expression?

Is it any different for compiled vs. interpreted languages?

Comment: No, not really. At least on compiled native languages like C/C++, no heap allocation is performed. However, some space can be allocated in the stack if there is not enough hardware registers to fit temporary values needed to compute an expression (in case of [register spilling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation)). For interpreter, variables can actually be allocated on the heap or on a (dedicated) stack.

Comment: Compilers and even intepreters (to a certain extent) perform some kind of optimization already.

And I think it's safe to say that in a high-level programming language there will be no noticeable performance improvement (let's say in terms of execution speed and memory consumption) if you do it this way or the other way.

There will be so many other things that will affect performance (like database calls or file system access and other infrastructure related stuff) before you hit problems at this level.

Comment: So unless you did some measurements and you until you really know you got a performance problem (or unless you are programming for microcontrollers on embedded systems) I would suggest to always aim for readability in your code first.